# How narratology used in biblical hermeneutics

Tags: hermeneutical-approaches, ecclesiastes

I am doing research on methodology in the hermeneutics of Ecclesiastes. Is [narratology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narratology) is a good method?
Garbo.

Comment: Welcome to BH. Please see the Tour and the Help as to the purpose and functioning of the site. Perhaps you could provide a link and a brief explanation of 'narratology' for those of us who do not know ?

Comment: _The term "narratology" is most typically applied to literary theory and literary criticism_ (Wikipedia). So I don't see how it is valid in the field of hermeneuitcs. Unless someone else can substantiate the opposite view from valid principles.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because although it could be considered a question about hermeneutics the question itself has not established that fact.

Comment: Welcome to BH. If the question would show SOME research on your part to make it meaningful here, I would like to see the answers. What intial impressions do you have reading Eccl that way give you the idea that it might be good?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. Now I am doing research on eccl. 7:25-29. This passage is talking about a woman. I try to use literary criticism to read this passage.

Comment: I am using the book of Bartholomew: Reading Ecclesiastes: Old Testament Exegesis and Hermeneutical Theory. This book has a chapter discussing about using narrative method study eccl.

Comment: But I know very little about using this method. I would like to ask if anyone can give me some advice.